# mysql - how can I select the min value if its status is equal to a particular value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to pull all tests out of a table if they were the first test taken that day and they passed.  Since MySQL only allows one field in a group by then I'm struggling to find a way to do it.  I've had a hunt around, and so far I'm up to:

```
select distinct 
    uut_serial_number,  
    MIN(START_DATE_TIME) as 'first test passed' 
from 
    uut_result 
where
    date(START_DATE_TIME) = '2016-06-16' 
and 
    uut_status = 'passed' 
group by uut_serial_number 

union

select distinct 
    uut_serial_number,  
    MIN(START_DATE_TIME) as 'first test taken' 
from 
    uut_result 
where
    date(START_DATE_TIME) = '2016-06-16' 
group by uut_serial_number;
```

It's giving me two records for each serial number with two test times. Logically if first < last then the unit failed its first test and the pass is the second figure, so I could run through it in code and sort them that way, but is there a way to do it in the query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your two queries is only this part `and uut_status = 'passed'` in the `where` clause of the first. However, it is possible to apply an additional filter during aggregation using an `case` expression in the aggregate function:

```
select uut_serial_number,  
     , MIN(CASE WHEN uut_status = 'passed'  THEN START_DATE_TIME END) as 'first test passed' 
     , MIN(START_DATE_TIME) as 'first test taken' 
  from 
       uut_result 
 where
       date(START_DATE_TIME) = '2016-06-16' 
 group by uut_serial_number
```

Only those rows satisfying `uut_status = 'passed'` are considered for this `min` expression (the others are ignored by `min` because aggregate functions ignore `null` and `else null` is implied for `case` when skipped).

You can then easily validate your first < last in the query itself (you have both in the same row now).

There is actually an less ugly way to write this in SQL, but MySQL doesn't support this out of the box. However, it might be easier to understand:

```
select uut_serial_number,  
     , MIN(START_DATE_TIME) FILTER(WHERE uut_status = 'passed') as 'first test passed' 
     , MIN(START_DATE_TIME) as 'first test taken' 
  from 
       uut_result 
 where
       date(START_DATE_TIME) = '2016-06-16' 
 group by uut_serial_number
```

The `FILTER` following the aggregate function `max` just specifies which rows to consider during the aggregation.

I've recently written an article about `filter` that also explains how the work around with `case` works:

- https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter

Comment: WHERE date(START_DATE_TIME) = '2016-06-16' **not use a index. FULL TABLE SCAN** - better: WHERE START_DATE_TIME '2016-06-16 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-16 23:59:59'

Comment: @Bernd Buffen even better: START_DATE_TIME >= '2016-06-16' AND START_DATE_TIME < '2016-06-17' (works with arbitrary time resolution, also fractions in seconds). However, I just kept it the way it is to not mix topics. However, fair addition.

Comment: You have a small typo Markus? Which I can't edit because SO thinks it's too small (they're probably right) - CASE  .... THEN should be CASE .... END and that's giving me the result I need.  Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

> Since MySQL only allows one field in a group by then I'm struggling to
>   find a way to do it.

MySQL do support grouping by multiple columns. You could use `GROUP BY` + `HAVING`:

```
SELECT
    uut_serial_number, uut_status
FROM
    uut_result 
WHERE
    DATE(START_DATE_TIME) = '2016-06-16'
GROUP BY uut_serial_number, uut_status
HAVING
    uut_status = 'passed' AND
    MIN(START_DATE_TIME) = (
        SELECT MIN(START_DATE_TIME) FROM uut_serial_number
        WHERE DATE(START_DATE_TIME) = '2016-06-16')
```